# Creating a QuerySet based on a ManyToManyField in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

So I've got two classes; Picture and Tag that are as follows:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
        pics = models.ManyToManyField('Picture', blank=True)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
        # stuff omitted

class Picture(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
        tags = models.ManyToManyField('Tag', blank=True)
        content = models.ImageField(upload_to='instaton')
        #stuff omitted
```

And what I'd like to do is get a queryset (for a ListView) given a tag name that contains the most recent X number of Pictures that are tagged as such. I've looked up very similar problems, but none of the responses make any sense to me at all. How would I go about creating this queryset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

tag = Tag.objects.get(name = 'tagname')

Picture.objects.filter(tags = tag).order_by('-pub_date')[X]

Comment: I got the following error:

invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'tagname'.

It looks like it was expecting tags to be an int?